# Lua Tilemap Specific Locations

Tags: lua, love2d

My code:

```
for mapy=0, 10 do
  for mapx=0, 13 do
    if map[mapy][mapx] == 0 then
        love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255)
        love.graphics.rectangle("line", mapx * 8, mapy * 8, (mapx * 8) + 64, (mapy * 8) + 64)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to test the specific row + column of `map` with `mapy` and `mapx` but it's only returning an error.

(The `love.graphics` is just setting the color to white, and drawing from `mapx` and `mapy`.)

I'm not even sure if this is the right way to do it, but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong.

The `map` is 13x10. As for the error, it's at the `if` statement.

> Attempt to index a nil value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in Lua use index beginning from `1`, not `0`. If the `map` is 13x10, then it should be:

```
for mapy = 1, 10 do
  for mapx = 1, 13 do
```